# devicePixelRatio on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, css, safari

On my iPhone 7 in Safari a 3in wide div is about 1.8in in real.

Why didn't they set devicePixelRatio so that 3in in css are 3in in real?
Is there a specification on how to set devicePixelRatio?
Is there a workaround?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0">
        <div style="width:3in;background:orange">3in</div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS units such as inch and cm are not recommended to use [according to w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html), except you're planning to print out your webpage:

> The only place where you could use pt (or cm or in) for setting a font size is in style sheets for print, if you need to be sure the printed font is exactly a certain size. But even there using the default font size is usually better.

If you really need to use inches as units, please take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141545/detecting-physical-screen-dimensions-of-webkit-devices-in-javascript/20888998#20888998)